Why installation of dotnet-ef fails even if --ignore-failed-sources is specified
I'm building a .NET 6 project via Azure DevOps Pipelines. One of the step is to install the Entity Framework tools so a later step can generate a SQL migration script.
However, the installation step fails with an 401 Unauthorized exception even the package seems to be found in the public nuget.org source. As --ignore-failed-sources is specified, having at least one hit should mark the overall call a success even the private feeds fails to find the package.
I've even tried to add the --version 6.* as the project is in .NET 6 but the overall result of the call remains the same.
Why am I getting the exception? How to fix that?
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" tool update --verbosity diagnostic --global --disable-parallel --version 6.* --ignore-failed-sources dotnet-ef
[NuGet Manager] [Info]   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/dotnet-ef/index.json
[NuGet Manager] [Info]   GET https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<private>/_packaging/<private>/nuget/v3/registrations2-semver2/dotnet-ef/index.json
[NuGet Manager] [Info]   GET https://nuget.<private>.com/v3/registration/dotnet-ef/index.json
[NuGet Manager] [Info]   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/dotnet-ef/index.json 70ms
[NuGet Manager] [Info]   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/dotnet-ef/page/0.0.1-alpha/3.1.28.json
[NuGet Manager] [Info]   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/dotnet-ef/page/0.0.1-alpha/3.1.28.json 32ms
[NuGet Manager] [Info]   Unauthorized https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<private>/_packaging/<private>/nuget/v3/registrations2-semver2/dotnet-ef/index.json 149ms
[NuGet Manager] [Info]   Unauthorized https://nuget.<private>.com/v3/registration/dotnet-ef/index.json 164ms
[NuGet Manager] [Info]   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/dotnet-ef/page/3.1.29/6.0.23.json
[NuGet Manager] [Info]   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/dotnet-ef/page/3.1.29/6.0.23.json 37ms
[NuGet Manager] [Info]   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/dotnet-ef/page/6.0.24/9.0.0-preview.6.24327.4.json
[NuGet Manager] [Info]   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/dotnet-ef/page/6.0.24/9.0.0-preview.6.24327.4.json 36ms
Unhandled exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.<>c__DisplayClass15_0`1.<<GetAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync[T](String filePath, Func`2 action, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync[T](String filePath, Func`2 action, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.GetAsync[T](HttpSourceCachedRequest request, Func`2 processAsync, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Protocol.PackageMetadataResourceV3.LoadRegistrationIndexAsync(HttpSource httpSource, Uri registrationUri, String packageId, SourceCacheContext cacheContext, Func`2 processAsync, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Protocol.PackageMetadataResourceV3.GetMetadataAsync(String packageId, Boolean includePrerelease, Boolean includeUnlisted, VersionRange range, SourceCacheContext sourceCacheContext, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)
   at NuGet.Protocol.PackageMetadataResourceV3.GetMetadataAsync(String packageId, Boolean includePrerelease, Boolean includeUnlisted, SourceCacheContext sourceCacheContext, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.NuGetPackageDownloader.NuGetPackageDownloader.GetPackageMetadataAsync(PackageSource source, String packageIdentifier, Boolean includePrerelease, Boolean includeUnlisted, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.NuGetPackageDownloader.NuGetPackageDownloader.GetMatchingVersionInternalAsync(String packageIdentifier, IEnumerable`1 packageSources, VersionRange versionRange, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.NuGetPackageDownloader.NuGetPackageDownloader.GetBestPackageVersionAsync(PackageId packageId, VersionRange versionRange, PackageSourceLocation packageSourceLocation)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.ToolPackage.ToolPackageDownloader.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<InstallPackage>b__0()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.TransactionalAction.Run[T](Func`1 action, Action commit, Action rollback)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Tool.Install.ToolInstallGlobalOrToolPathCommand.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<Execute>b__1()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Tool.Install.ToolInstallGlobalOrToolPathCommand.RunWithHandlingInstallError(Action installAction)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Tool.Install.ToolInstallGlobalOrToolPathCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Tool.Update.ToolUpdateGlobalOrToolPathCommand.Execute()
   at System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.Invoke(ParseResult parseResult)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, TimeSpan startupTime, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about the breaking changes here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : [ '' ]
Finishing: Install dotnet-ef

Excerpt of the yml file:
variables:
- name: BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects
  value: '**/*.csproj'
- name: BuildParameters.TestProjects
  value: '**/*[Tt]ests/*.csproj'
- name: BuildConfiguration
  value: 'release'

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - refs/heads/master

name: $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)

jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Agent job 1
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-2022
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Restore
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '$(BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
      feedsToUse: 'config'
      nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
      externalFeedCredentials: 'Telerik NuGet source'
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Build
    inputs:
      projects: $(BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects)
      arguments: --configuration $(BuildConfiguration)
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Test
    enabled: False
    inputs:
      command: test
      projects: $(BuildParameters.TestProjects)
      arguments: --configuration $(BuildConfiguration)
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Publish
    inputs:
      command: publish
      publishWebProjects: True
      projects: $(BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects)
      arguments: --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      zipAfterPublish: True
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
    inputs:
      TargetPath: '\\my\share\$(Build.DefinitionName)\$(Build.BuildNumber)'
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Install dotnet-ef
    inputs:
      command: 'custom'
      custom: 'tool'
      arguments: 'update --verbosity diagnostic --global --disable-parallel --version 6.* --ignore-failed-sources dotnet-ef'

The agent's self-identification:
Starting: Initialize job
Agent name: 'Hosted Agent'
Agent machine name: 'fv-az510-690'
Current agent version: '3.241.0'
Operating System
Microsoft Windows Server 2022
10.0.20348
Datacenter
Runner Image
Image: windows-2022
Version: 20240723.1.0
Included Software: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/win22/20240723.1/images/windows/Windows2022-Readme.md
Image Release: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/releases/tag/win22%2F20240723.1
Runner Image Provisioner
2.0.373.1
Current image version: '20240723.1.0'
Agent running as: 'VssAdministrator'

The task's self-identification:
Starting: Install dotnet-ef
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.242.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001


Provide the detailed YAML of your pipeline. What agent are you using to run the pipeline job? Microsoft-hosted agents, or Self-hosted agents installed on yourself local machines or VMs?

Hi @BrightRan-MSFT, thanks. I've just added the requested information into the question.

Does this help? https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/36473#issuecomment-1887615945 and https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/11837#issuecomment-2225151325

@alik, Have you tried the suggestions shared in my answer below? Does it work for you?

I've followed the workarounds in issues linked by @rui-jarimba, i.e. create a separate nuget.config file and add an argument instructing to use it.

If there is a NuGet configuration file (nuget.config) exists in the current working directory where to run the command "dotnet tool install" or "dotnet tool update", the command will use the nuget.config file by default. So, the command also will verify the credentials of the package sources (feeds) set in the nuget.config file. If the nuget.config file has private package sources set, you might get the 401 Unauthorized error when running the command.
To avoid this issue, you can try one of the following methods:

Change the working directory of the command to another directory that does not contain any nuget.config file. The task will run the command in the specified directory. The specified directory only available for current DotNetCoreCLI@2 task and not change the working directory on other tasks.
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Install EF Core CLI'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: tool
    arguments: 'install dotnet-ef --global --version 6.*'
    workingDirectory: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Verify EF Core CLI'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: ef



Add a NuGetAuthenticate@1 task before running the run the command "dotnet tool install" or "dotnet tool update" to generate the credentials that can access the private package sources.

For the feeds inside the current Azure DevOps organization, this task will automatically build the credentials.
For the feeds outside the current Azure DevOps organization, you need to provide the NuGet service connections on this task to connect to the outside feeds. This task support specifying multiple NuGet service connections.

- task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
  displayName: 'NuGet Authenticate'
  inputs:
    nuGetServiceConnections: 'Connection_outsideFeed01, Connection_outsideFeed02'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Install EF Core CLI'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: tool
    arguments: 'install dotnet-ef --global --version 6.*'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Verify EF Core CLI'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: ef






The purpose of --ignore-failed-sources switch is to ignore the failures on authenticated feeds as Entity Framework tools are available on the public feed. However, the argument fails to have an effect in this case. I've followed the workarounds in issues linked by @rui-jarimba, i.e. create a separate nuget.config file and add an argument instructing to use it.

@alik, The nuget.config file is not optional and not required.
